# Guava Table ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, guava

I'm reading through some code that uses a Guava table and occasionally throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` - which I understand because I'm iterating through the Table's columns and modifying the table in the same loop.  Is there a clean/performant way to solve this?  Can I do a table.remove before the put and expect it to work?

```
final Set<Optional<SimpleWorkDataValue>> columnKeys = table.columnKeySet();
for (final SimpleWorkDataValue timeSeriesValue : timeSeriesValues) {
    final Optional<SimpleWorkDataValue> rowKey = Optional.of(timeSeriesValue);
    for (final Optional<SimpleWorkDataValue> columnKey : columnKeys) {
        if (!table.contains(rowKey, columnKey)) {
            table.put(rowKey, columnKey, ResultSet.EMPTY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The obvious solution is to use a temporary table then `table.putAll(temp);` - not sure if you can find something more efficient than that.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer so I can upvote.  I'll try it out.  Also it would be helpful to see it in a snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the row, column, and cell counts involved in the typical execution of your nested loop, you could potentially save on memory by factoring out the Iterator that gets implicitly instantiated in this code line here:

```
    for (final Optional<SimpleWorkDataValue> columnKey : columnKeys) {
```

Since this Iterable doesn't change throughout the entire procedure, you could copy the column keys to a List in the beginning, and then iterate over that instead in the inner loop:

```
    final List<Optional<SimpleWorkDataValue>> columnKeyList =
        ImmutableList.copyOf(table.columnKeySet());
    for (final SimpleWorkDataValue timeSeriesValue : timeSeriesValues) {
        final Optional<SimpleWorkDataValue> rowKey = Optional.of(timeSeriesValue);
        for (final Optional<SimpleWorkDataValue> columnKey : columnKeyList) {
            if (!table.contains(rowKey, columnKey)) {
                table.put(rowKey, columnKey, ResultSet.EMPTY);
            }
        }
    }
```

And, of course, this should eliminate all ConcurrentModificationExceptions

Comment: Great answer.  Can you elaborate why this removes the concurrent modification exception?  Aren't I still updating the table while iterating over it?

Comment: @AmirAfghani `columnKeyList` is a copy of the columnKeySet, so technically you are not iterating on the columnKeySet any more.

Comment: I see...So should I use something like Immutable.copyOf instead?  Is that inefficient?

Comment: assylias is correct.  Whenever you write to a Collections structure, typically an internal modCount integer is incremented, and Iterators check this count to detect multi-threaded conflict so that they can fail quickly, preserving the good state of the data in the table.  When you copy all the column keys into the ArrayList before hand, you no longer need the Iterator that checks the mod count, since you're using a totally separate structure.  Hence, no more errors.

Comment: maybe collections.unmodifiable list is cleaner too incase you want to update your answer

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate around my comment:

```
//a temporary table
Table<Optional<SimpleWorkDataValue>, Optional<SimpleWorkDataValue>, Object> temp =
    HashBasedTable.create();

for (final SimpleWorkDataValue timeSeriesValue : timeSeriesValues) {
    final Optional<SimpleWorkDataValue> rowKey = Optional.of(timeSeriesValue);
    for (final Optional<SimpleWorkDataValue> columnKey : columnKeys) {
        if (!table.contains(rowKey, columnKey)) {
 //here add to temp instead of table
            temp.put(rowKey, columnKey, ResultSet.EMPTY);
        }
    }
}

//after loop, put everyting back into table
table.putAll(temp);
```